How to find the derivative of Frobenius Norm with respect to the matrix?
I have a real square matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. I compute its Frobenius norm $y$. So $y$ is a scalar. Now I want to compute the derivative  $\frac{dy}{dX}$. How to do that?

Let $X$ be $m\times n$. You asked about the case $m=n$, but we can discuss the more general situation.
Let $X^i_j$ denote the row $i$, column $j$ entry of $X$. Let $\|X\|$ denote the Frobenius norm of $X$. Note that $$\|X\|^2=\sum_{p,q}[X^p_q]^2,$$ so $$2\|X\| \frac{\partial }{\partial X^i_j}\|X\| = \frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}\sum_{p,q}[X^p_q]^2=\sum_{p,q}\frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}[X^p_q]^2=2X^i_j.$$ The first equality is just the chain rule. The second follows from the fact that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}[X^p_q]^2=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2X^i_j & : p = i, q=j\\ 0 & : \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$
So $$\frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}\|X\| = \frac{X^i_j}{\|X\|}.$$
We can summarize this as $$\frac{d \|X\|}{dX}=\frac{X}{\|X\|}.$$

In the definition of  Frobenius norm, we should use absolute value | | rather than the current []. right?

There's a closely related question. Could you help me, thank you! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4894290/how-to-get-the-derivative-of-the-frobenius-norm-squared-with-respect-to-the-matr

Looks like someone else beat me to it.
