How to get the derivative of the Frobenius norm squared with respect to the matrix?
Let $X$ be $m\times n$. The Frobenius norm of a matrix $X$ is defined as:
$$\|X\| = \sqrt{\sum_{p, q} (X^p_q)^2}$$
Then how to get $\frac{d\|X\|^2}{dX}$?

$$\frac{\partial||\mathbf X||^2}{\partial X_{ij}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}\sum_{p,q}X_{pq}^2=\sum_{p,q}\frac{\partial X_{pq}^2}{\partial X_{ij}}=2X_{ij}\overset{\forall i,j}{\iff} \frac{\partial||\mathbf X||^2}{\partial \mathbf X}=2\mathbf X$$
